# OSGI and different mail.jar send plain text attachement, throw exception: "text/plain" DataContentHandler requires String object,

Tags: java, osgi, email-attachments

In my env, two different mail jars exist in two different Classloaders, since our requirement is to keep two version of mail jar work together.

but when sending a plain-text attachment, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: "text/plain" DataContentHandler requires String object, was given object of type class [B
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.writeTo(text_plain.java:152)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1476)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865)
    at iaik.smime.SMimeBodyPart.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462)
    at com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.BCMimeMultipart.writeTo(BCMimeMultipart.java:186)
    at com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.BCMultipartMixed.writeTo(BCMultipartMixed.java:77)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1476)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1772)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1748)
    at com.tibco.ax.ebms3.runtime.outbound.EBMS3OBMimeMessage.encodeMessage(EBMS3OBMimeMessage.java:275)
```

Comment: this question is missing the code that produces it, please add it (in an edit to the question, or if you cant, in a comment).

Comment: Thanks, @hoijui , finally i resolved it

Answer (score 0):

This week I focus on research this issue, finally I figured out.  Here is my analysis and resolution.

Basically, Its related to MailCapCommand  Map(defaultCommandMap ,a system static map defined in JRE , that class name is CommandMap.java) and  both two ClassLoader updated MailCapCommand Map in EBXML runtime evn, when enabled “Automaticlly update SAML token”.

Details is  when BC interior server start up,  the class SMIMEUtil.init() will load mail caps defined in file “com/tibco/ax/fw/ediint/resource/defaultMailcap.properties”, that include

```
        text/*;;x-java-content-handler=com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.DefaultTextHandler
```

And when SBR load SBR’s jars also will load mail caps from they logic, and they add two special mail cap command that is

```
        text/xml={content-handler=[com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.XmlDataContentHandler]
```

text/plain={content-handler=[com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StringDataContentHandler]   // Not that jars from SBR

and PP send transactions with attachment, then the mail.jar logic will try to find a DataContentHandler from MailCapCommand Map through contentType. For instance, QA test case is “text/plain”, so program will get the com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StringDataContentHandler to process content, but unfortunately, that class is loaded by our customize SBR ClassLoader, in IS ClassLoader can’t find this class, so system will get the system default com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain  to process the content. But in com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain, we must pass a String object instead of  a byte array as the parameter of writeTo method. So the exception “java.io.IOException: ‘text/plain’ DataContentHandler requires String object, was given object of type class [B” was throw out.

What my resolution is add below two mailcap to MailCapCommand Map when starting BC Interior Server in class SMIMEUtil.init().

```
 CommandMap mimeMap = CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;;x-java-content-handler=com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.DefaultTextHandler");
     mc.addMailcap("text/xml;;x-java-content-handler=com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.DefaultTextHandler");
```

Since we always handle text/plian and text/xml as text in our BC program. So above codes have no any harm to BC Interior Server. But it could be bring some issues for SBR request with attachment. But luck to us, we don’t use this feature, we only simple send HTTP request to get SMAL token. So it also ok to SAML part.

Last I did the text with my resolution, It’s works well both for IS and SAML update.

If you have any goods suggestion please let me know.

Comment: So have you answered your own question?

Comment: Yes, finally, resolove it by myself.

Comment: Can you post the solution? Otherwise this question is useless on StackOverflow.

Comment: @NeilBartlett My solution is the answer that my post. basiclly is after customize classloader loaded the classes to JVM, and then force to load mailcups to Map.                                                                     `CommandMap mimeMap = CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;;x-java-content-handler=com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.DefaultTextHandler");
     mc.addMailcap("text/xml;;x-java-content-handler=com.tibco.ax.fw.mime.DefaultTextHandler");`